# Cannot read property 'setState' of null

Tags: reactjs

im starting ReactJS and i try to use Firebase as a database to collect my data. Im stuck from 2 days now cause of this error : "Cannot read property 'setState' of null"

I can read my data from Firebase but i can't display them... I don't really know what to do :

```
import React from 'react';
import ProductList from '../Product/ProductList';
import Firebase from 'firebase';

class HomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      productList: []
    }

    var firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://codehunt-one.firebaseio.com/');
    firebaseRef.child("products").on('value', function(snapshot) {
      var products = snapshot.val();
      console.log(products);

      this.setState({
        productList: products
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <header>
          <img src="img/banner.jpeg" width="100%" />
        </header>

        <section>
          <section className="container">
              {this.state.productList
                ?
                <ProductList productList={this.state.productList}/>
                :
                null
              }

          </section>
        </section>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 6):

The value of `this` in a JavaScript function differs depending on how it was called. When specifying a callback function like this, the outer scope will not be preserved as it will be called from another context. Check out [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for a more in depth explanation.

You can explicitly set the value of `this` by using `bind`:

```
firebaseRef.child("products").on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var products = snapshot.val();

  this.setState({
    productList: products
  })
}.bind(this));
```

Or you can simply use an arrow function which uses lexical scoping. This basically means that the outer scope will be preserved as you seem to be expecting in this case:

```
firebaseRef.child("products").on('value', (snapshot) => {
  var products = snapshot.val();

  this.setState({
    productList: products
  })
});
```

Comment: Okay, Now i got this error : TypeError: this.props.productList.map is not a function

Comment: This probably means that productList has been assigned to something that isn't an array. Maybe snapshot.val() isn't returning an array as expected?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `this.setState` in the constructor because `this` is not available yet. Instead, move that piece of logic to `componentWillMount` and it should start working.

```
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      productList: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://codehunt-one.firebaseio.com/');
    firebaseRef.child("products").on('value', function(snapshot) {
      var products = snapshot.val();
      console.log(products);

      this.setState({
        productList: products
      })
    });
  }
```